# I am stuck on my programming project

Tags: structure, controls

A large company pays its salespeople on a commission basis. The salespeople receive $200 per week plus 9% of their gross sales for that week. For example, a salesperson who sells $5000 worth of merchandise in a week receives $200 plus 9% of $5000, or a total of $650. Your program will allow the user to enter item numbers for each item sold by the salesperson for that week, print out the total of each item sold by the salesperson, and the total weekly earnings for that salesperson. The items and values are: Item 1 equals to 5.00, Item 2 equals to 10.00, Item 3 equals to 1.00, Item 4 equals to 25.00. Program should use JOptionPane for all input.
I have some programmed but I only get one input.

--- Update ---

//This is what I have so far

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

```
public class KingRocker {
public static void main( String[]args )
{

double gross = 0.0, earnings;
int product = 0, number;
String input;

while( product < 4 ){
product++;
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of products sold   #" + product + " ");

number = Integer.parseInt( input );

if (product == 1)
gross = gross + number * 5.00;
else if (product == 2)
gross = gross + number * 10.00;
else if (product == 3)
gross = gross + number * 1.00;
else if (product == 4)
gross = gross + number * 25.00;

earnings = 0.09 * gross + 200;

String result = "Week earnings: " + earnings;

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result, "Sales",      JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );

System.exit( -1);
}
 }
  }
```

Comment: You have System.exit in the inner loop.

Comment: what is your question in this code?

Comment: Can we assume this is your school work? But yet you have to post your question, as it is not visible in your current post...

Comment: Thanks but how would I get the outputs? I only have one when I need 4 of them

Comment: How would I make it print out the total of each item sold by the salesperson, and the total weekly earnings for that salesperson.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you are calling `System.exit( -1);` before you run though the rest of your while loop. Try moving `System.exit( -1);` outside of the loop.

Try closing the loops here

```
if (product == 1)
gross = gross + number * 5.00;
else if (product == 2)
gross = gross + number * 10.00;
else if (product == 3)
gross = gross + number * 1.00;
else if (product == 4)
gross = gross + number * 25.00;
}
```

Doing so will allow the loop to run four times.  Giving you what you ask for in the comments.